# Performing Euclidean Distance Measure on Documents (i.e., text) Using Sci-Kit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new to machine learning.  After a lot of research, I've decided to use Sci-Kit Learn as much as possible in my efforts.  But I'm still at square one.

What I would like to do is perform a euclidean distance measurement on my documents.  I am using NLTK to prep the text and Sci-Kit to [extract document features](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).  What I'd like to do now is measure the documents' euclidean distance.

Here is [Sci-Kit's documentation for euclidean distance measurement](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances).  It's not clear to me (the newb) which features I should be passing the function (i.e., euclidean_distances()).  Can anyone tell me what I need to pass Sci-Kit's euclidean distances function??

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just feed it the output of the vectorizer's `fit_transform` method.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

v = TfidfVectorizer()
X = v.fit_transform(your_documents)
D = euclidean_distances(X)
```

Now `D[i, j]` is the Euclidean distance between document vectors `X[i]` and `X[j]`.

Comment: Thank you very very much, Larsmans, for your answer.  If it's not against policy I will ask you a quick follow-up.  Can you point me to a Sci-Kit resource (if there is one) that allows/helps convert my different measurements (now cosine and euclidean) into formats that can be used in the different algorithms?

Comment: I ask because I am trying to complete a [kNN analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_nearest_centroid.html#example-neighbors-plot-nearest-centroid-py) on my documents -- so that when a person "likes" one document I can recommend another him/her a similar doc -- but that algorithm requires a different format.  It passes two parameters to clf.fit(), for instance, X and y.  In this case "X" is a 2D array (...[ 6.7  3. ] [ 6.3  2.5][ 6.5  3. ][ 6.2  3.4][ 5.9  3. ]]), I believe, and "y" is a 1D array ([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2]).

Comment: I think it could really help demystify SciKit ML algorithms for me if there were a resource that helped place my text-based numbers (mostly vectors and matrices) into a format that is used in the non-text-based examples.  Thanks for any thoughts.  If my question doesn't make sense I'd be happy to try to better explain; and of course no problem if SciKit doesn't support what I'm asking about, as that would explain why I haven't found it yet :).  Thank you!!

Comment: @BeeSmears: I hope you don't mind if I redirect you to the [scikit-learn mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/scikit-learn-general). I read that, as do other developers and users, and the policies aren't as strict as on SO so there's more room for discussion.

Comment: Not at all.  I'll take any opportunity I can get for better SciKit understanding.  Thanks much, Larsmans!